# Multiple arguments IsNull function MS Access VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a procedure to that checks multiple textboxes on a form (but not all) to see if they're null, and currently I am using this code:

```
If IsNull(control1) Or IsNull(control2) Or IsNull(control3)... etc
```

Is there a way to concisely check multiple textboxes for null values without `Or` operators?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sum of Null plus any non-Null value is Null.  So add those control values and if one or more of them is Null, the sum will be Null:

```vb
If IsNull(control1 + control2 + control3) Then
```

Comment: Thanks, that was what I was after

Answer (score 1):

No, that's as concise as it gets.

If you really want, you can build your own function using **ParamArray**.

See [Optional Parameters To Procedures](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/optionalargumentstoprocedures.aspx) (second part **ParamArray Parameter Type**)